# Regex to search for words containing foreign characters

Tags: regex, notepad++, unicode-string

I'm looking for a RegEx for use in Notepad++ that picks out lines with foreign words. My strategy is to try and catch words containing foreign characters. For example, if I wanted to find uppercase Greek words I've come as close as

```
^(?< ![a-z0-9]).+\[ΓΣΩΘΦΔΛΠ\](?!=a-z0-9)+$
```

which attempts to locate any of these uppercase Greek letters with negative lookarounds on both sides for lowercase letters and numbers but it doesn't work.

If I crafted a working expression lines such as:

```
1. BUTTER ΘEΦECOC EGGS
2. Flour CREAM sugar
3. AΘINA HELLAΣ ΠOΘCON
```

should match only lines 1 & 3, as 2 has no words with Greek letters.

Comment: maybe [^a-zA-Z\s0-9\.\;\:\,]

Comment: "Foreign" is not an exact term :) The letter 'k' only appears in 'foreign' words in Italian, for example. Perhaps you mean "characters outside the regular ASCII set"?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know that non-English words may as well be in the form `[a-z]+`, you can match a word with a code point in the Unicode General Category Letter using [`\pL`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

**Match lines:**

```
(?i).*(?![a-z])\pM*\pL.*
```

**Match words:**

```
(?i)\b[a-z]*(?![a-z])\pM*\pL\w*
```

---

**Explanation**

- `(?i)` caseless match.
- `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to match the beginning of a word.
- `[a-z]*` matches English letters that may appear in the word before a non-English letter.
- `(?![a-z])\pM*\pL` uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert the next character is not an English letter, and then it matches a code point in the [Unicode General Category Letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm), possibly preceded by a diacritic.
- `\w*` to match any other word character.